# Set custom field value in customer registration

Tags: magento-1.7, register, custom-variable

I created a custom field named **location_city** in customer. In the admin, under Account Information tab, the name of the field is: **account[location_city]**

Now during new registration, I want to set the value of this field. I wanted to get the city, state etc. of user from ip address. Here is my code:

```
        include('Ipinfo\Host.php');
        include('Ipinfo\Ipinfo.php');

        $ipInfo = new Ipinfo\Ipinfo();

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        $host = $ipInfo->getFullIpDetails($ip);

        if(isset($host))
            $city = $host->getCity();
        else
            $city = "N/A";

        $customer->setData('location_city', $city);
        $customer->setData("account['location_city']", $city);
        $customer->setLocationcity($city);
        $customer->setLocationCity($city);
        $customer->setLocation_city($city);
```

None of the last five lines are working, city is always blank in admin.

The script I used to create the custom field is this:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/setup', 'customer_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer','location_city', array(
'label'             => 'Source City',
'type'              => 'text',    //backend_type
'input'             => 'text', //frontend_input
'global'            =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible'           => true,
'required'          => false,
'default'           => '',
'frontend'          => '',
'unique'            => false,
'note'              => ''
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer', 'location_city')
->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_address_edit',
    'checkout_onepage_register', 'checkout_onepage_register_guest', 'checkout_onepage_billing_address',
    'adminhtml_customer','checkout_onepage_shipping_address','checkout_multishipping_register'
))
->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Please help what to do,

Thanks

Comment: In other words attribute successfully added and you can store values there. And you think that the issue is with Ipinfo module

Comment: Is there any error in error log?

Comment: No Ipinfo is not causing problem. If there is no value, city should be "N/A". Also, registration is being done without any errors.